# c++ division by 0

Tags: c++, divide-by-zero

I am running long simulations. I record the results into a vector to compute statistics about the data. I realized that, in theory, those samples could be the result of a division by zero; this is only theoretical, I am pretty sure it's not the case. In order to avoid rerunning the simulation after modifying the code, I was wondering what happens in that case. Would I be able to realize whether a division by 0 has occurred or not? Will I get error messages? (Exceptions are not being handled at the moment).

Thanks

Comment: What type are we talking here? float?

Answer (score 57):

For IEEE floats, division of a finite nonzero float by 0 is well-defined and results in +infinity (if the value was >zero) or -infinity (if the value was less than zero). The result of 0.0/0.0 is NaN. If you use integers, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Just to be clear, if a float 0.0 is divided by an integer 0, the integer would be cast as a float and the result is NaN, correct?

Comment: Yes, result will be NAN

Answer (score 11):

Note that C standard says (6.5.5):

> The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of
>   the first operand by the second; the result of the % operator is the
>   remainder. In both operations, if the value of the second operand is
>   zero, the behavior is undefined.

So something/0 is undefined (by the standard) both for integral types and Floating points. Nevertheless most implementations have fore mentioned behavior (+-INF or NAN).

Comment: It's worth noting that at least in C, if an implementation declares support for [C standard Annex F](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) (optional), Annex F overrides 6.5.5 for floating-point types and renders floating-point division by zero defined. I don't think the standard explicitly states this, but there are several parts of Annex F that specify things about how division by zero must or must not behave.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking integers then your program should crash upon division by zero.

If you're talking floats then division by zero is allowed and the result to that is INF or -INF. Now it's all up to your code if the program will crash, handle that nicely or continue with undefined/unexpected results.

Comment: Undefined behavior ≠ crash

Answer (score 0):

If you use IEEE floats, then it will return 0 or NaN. If the op1 is 0, you will get undefined. If op1 is higher than 0, you will get Infinity. If op1 is lower than 0, then you will get -Infinity. If you use dividing by 0 directly or in integer , you will get error "Floating point exception".

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double a = 123, b = 0;
    double result = a/b;

    string isInfinite = isinf(result) ? "is" : "is not";
    cout << "result=" << result << " " << isInfinite << " infinity" << endl;
}
```

result=inf is infinity