# how to do generic division without raising exception

Tags: c++, exception, math, division, infinity

I want to do safe division for any type T, which I don't want to raise CPU/FPU exception, for example if a float is divided by zero it should return infinity (+/-INF).

Should I write my own function? or is there any standard C++ function that I can use?

if I need to write my own function, does this function is right?

```
template<typename T> bool isSameSign(const T& a, const T& b)
{       
    return ((((a)<0)==((b)<0))&&(((a)>0)==((b)>0)));
}

template<typename T> T safeDiv (const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
    if(std::abs(rhs) > std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon)
    {
        if(std::abs(lhs) > std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon)
        {
            return lhs/rhs;
        }
        else
        {
            return std::numeric_limits<T>::quiet_NaN();
        }
    }
    else if(isSameSign<T>(lhs,rhs))
    {
        return std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity();
    }
    else
    {
        return -std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745311/c-division-by-0

Comment: Float division by zero already returns infinity in C++.

Comment: @scott : I'am doing generic type of division, not just float

Comment: @uray do you mean integers or something else?

Comment: @uray : `numeric_limits<>::epsilon` is only meaningful for floating-point types, so this code can't be all _that_ generic...

Comment: @ildjarn: numeric_limits<> can be expanded/specialized to other type than floating-point

Comment: What does "division division for any type T" even mean? My path class has an `path path::operator/(const char*)`. Allows for funky expresssions like `RootDir/"temp"`, but that's certainly not a division. More seriously, check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring - there are many reasonable mathematical types for which division is highly non-trivial.

Comment: Also, even complex numbers (a very reasonable type to divide) can't be compared against zero like you do. They don't even _have_ a sign. And therefore, they don't have +INF and -INF either. (+INF, 0) and (0, +INF), yes, and also (+INF,+INF).

Comment: @uray : "Can be" and "are" are two different things. ;-]

Answer (score 1):

If a float is divided by zero, mathematically speaking, it is undefined, not infinity. The reason is the law of limits. As you divide by a smaller and smaller number greater than zero, you tend to approach positive infinity, and as you divide by a smaller and smaller negative number you tend toward negative infinity.... On a number line those are opposites, and you can't define one thing as both of those opposites. The function 1/x  is therefore undefined at 0. Returning negative or positive infinity would be incorrect.

Comment: division by zero is just an example, i'am trying to handle division by number smaller than epsilon here

Comment: @Zak, that's why there's both a positive and a negative zero.