# Dividing a double number with a double of 0 gives the limit of the expression and not error

Tags: c, math, double

I've been asked the result of this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{

    double a =0;

    double b =2/ a;

    printf("b=%f\n", b);

    printf("SLABC\n");

    return 0;

}
```

running it, the code prints `b=inf` and `SLABC` and then exists correctly.

I could not understand why the division of 2/0 does not rise an error (had it been `int a=0`, I'd get the appropriate runtime error), and my only assumption is that in type double, a=0 actually doesn't mean that **a is 0**, but rather that **a is very close to 0** (and apparently, a>0 and not the negative, or it should have been -inf).

I get the same result even if `a=0.0` and `a=0.00000000`. Feels to me like the computer has decided to calculate the limit of this expression (calculus style), but I suppose there is a more sensible explantation. Also, I'm not clear as to why its only positive, and not negative.

Comment: You can check the divide-by-zero flag.

Comment: it refers to the `floating point` and the architecture of doubles , if you use `int` instead of `double` you will see the error

Comment: Possible [dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745311/c-division-by-0)?

Comment: The float/double value 0.0 means the value is so small, it cannot be represented on this architecture (but may in reality not be zero!). Hence the result is so large, it can neither be represented on this architecture and so is +/-INF on this architecture. (Clever, now that I think about this.)

Comment: @George If C is specified to behave like C++ concerning division by 0, then this is a dupe of [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745311/c-division-by-0) or visa-versa and that post should also be tagged C.  I do not see that as so.  The two languages C and C++ certainly have similarities, especially concerning FP math and that post is related.  There is also the question of how each languages species IEEE 754 adherence or not,  which plays into divide-by-0 questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ division by 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745311/c-division-by-0)

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is proper floating point division.

The values infinity and negative infinity are valid floating point values, as well as "not-a-number".

When floating point division is done with a 0 divisor, the result will infinity with the sign matching the dividend.

If you were to calculate `0.0/0.0` or `inf/inf`, the result would be `NaN`, i.e. not-a-number.

Comment: Is it *always* the case, or it might rise an exception on some archs?

Answer (score 1):

C explicitly identifies this as *undefined behavior* (UB).

> The result of the `/` operator is the quotient ...  if the value of the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined. C11dr §6.5.5 5

C does not define that the code should error.

Assigning a "value" of infinity with a sign that is the exclusive-or of the signs of finite  operands is a common result.

This matches [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) behavior "The default result of divideByZero shall be an ∞ correctly signed according to the operation:"  Adherence to IEEE 754 is not required by C, although many platforms strive for it.

Answer (score 0):

In **floats** or **doubles**, division by zero is allowed and the result to that is `+-INF` or `+-NAN`.

Comment: It's return +-NAN.