# exception_ptr in a catch-all handler works oddly on both Centos 7 and Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, c++11

To avoid stacking catch blocks in writing exception handling code, I thought to try to write a catch-all exception handler using the c++11 features. In doing so I noticed some odd behavior that worked the same way on both Centos 7 and Windows 7 and 8.1 using Code::Blocks IDE on both systems (you have to check the settings->compiler->c++11 ISO checkbox to get this to work.) I had two kinds of exceptions, a hardware divide by zero *(number1/number2)* and a synthetic divide by zero function *quotient(number1, number2)* that throws a declared exception when there is a zero denominator. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

class DivideByZero : public runtime_error
{
public:
    DivideByZero() :
        runtime_error("Divide by zero exception") {}
};

template <typename T>
T quotient(T numer, T denom)
{
    if (denom == 0)
    {
        throw DivideByZero();
    }
    else
    {
        return numer / denom;
    }
}

int main()
{
    double number1, number2, ratio;
    cout << "Enter a numerator: ";
    cin >> number1;
    cout << "Enter a denominator: ";
    cin >> number2;
    try
    {
        ratio = number1/number2;
        //ratio = quotient(number1, number2);
        cout << "Result is: " << ratio << endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::exception_ptr p = std::current_exception();
        cerr << "Exception: "
             << (p ?
                 p.__cxa_exception_type()->name() :
                 "Anonymous")
             << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would comment out the hardware or the synthetic division code line and then build/run with different integer and real types.

The results were similar on both Centos 7 and the Windows systems, for i5 and i7 Intel processors.

When executing the synthetic divide (quotient) line that throws a declared exception on all systems, it worked the same way for all the integer and real types, correctly printing out the exception number and the declared exception text to cerr:

```
Exception: 12DivideByZero
```

Pretty nice, no more stacking exceptions and missing any that might occur!

However, when executing the hardware divide line (number1/number2) for both integer and real types, the exception handling was bypassed completely in different ways. For real types like double, the exception is caught and the the cerr text is not printed, what comes out is the display line printed after the code causing the exception, **which you should not see** and what appears to be the infinite value for all the real types:

```
Result is: inf
```

For all integer types you don't even get that, you get no display line and on Linux it ends normally, on Windows it dies and goes looking for a solution to your bad program.

Seems odd to me, I'm sure some maven will explain the lack of consistency in exception handling in c++11.

the Code::Blocks on both Windows systems was using a recent download of the mingw32-g++.exe for compiling, and of course, Centos 7 is using the 64 bit g++ compiler. Not that it made any difference, the systems behaved similarly.

Comment: Do you expect `number1/number2` to throw an exception? It generally doesn't. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4745343/3484570).

Comment: I was testing divide by zero. For integer types it just died instead of catch-all, which should catch it, I thought.

Comment: @Charlie...: Let's rephrase that then: Do you expect `number1/number2` to throw an exception when `number2==0`? Because on most platforms it doesn't. (The "generally" in nwp's comment refrs to various implementations, not divisors)

Answer (score 0):

> **[expr.mul]/4** The binary `/` operator yields the quotient, and the binary `%` operator yields the remainder from the division of the first expression by the second. If the second operand of `/` or `%` is zero the behavior is undefined...

When zero is entered for `number2`, your program exhibits undefined behavior. Which means that any outcome at all is possible; the C++ standard places no requirements on the behavior of such a program.

Comment: It occurs to me that "undefined behavior" is what you get for any uncaught exception. I don't mean to just be a purist, but a "catch-all" exception handler should not mean "catch-most". It should keep the program alive from any one exception and doesn't mean it will tolerate what comes next.

In the Linux case "number1/number2" stayed alive and terminated normally, but did not execute the handler, even though it could have.

In the Windows case "number1/number2" did the abnormal program exit search for solutions even though it could have executed the handler as well.

Comment: ["Undefined behavior"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) is what you get for many different things, one of which is "division by zero". Undefined behavior may manifest by throwing an exception, or by the program crashing, or by the program appearing to work but producing incorrect results, or even by the program appearing to work and behave as its author expects. See also: [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). You cannot recover from UB, with `catch(...)` or otherwise - the only course of action is fix the bug so UB doesn't occur in the first place.

Comment: And in fact, uncaught exception doesn't give rise to undefined behavior. The behavior of an uncaught exception is specified by the standard: "**[except.handle]/9** If no matching handler is found, the function `std::terminate()` is called..." . But in any case, this is all moot: division by zero is not required to, and generally does not - I repeat does not - throw any exception, so there's nothing for `catch(...)` to catch.

Comment: I would disagree about this, and this will be my final comment.

1.This part of the standard would appear to be what I call an "infantile appendage", a legacy of the C standard of the last century, and does not appear futuristic.

2. Evolution of the C++ standard programming model should include changes to make programs more robust, not less.

3. Being able to tolerate failures in the C++ standard model, without failing the program back to some operating system widget, or a TP Monitor, or something written in python, would seem desirable.

4. If so, try/catch-all needs to catch-all.