# Why is if Statement not returning INFINITY? C++

Tags: c++

I have writed this Program and it should print **INFINITY** if Divided by **0** for example according to the code **0/0 = infinity** thus the output is not as I expect. Something is wrong with my code? or I need to do it on another way?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void optionMenu();
void userInput(char);

int main ()
{
    optionMenu();
    char userResult;
    cout << " Choice: ";
    cin >> userResult;
    userInput(userResult);
    return 0;
}
void optionMenu()
{
    cout << " Enter your choice" << '\n' ;
    cout << " + for Addition" << '\n';
    cout << " - for Subtraction" << '\n';
    cout << " * for Multiplication" << '\n';
    cout << " / for Division" << '\n';
}
void userInput(char userResult)
{
    int value1, value2;
    switch (userResult)
    {
        case '+':
        cout << " Enter your first Number: "; cin >> value1; cout << " Enter your second number: "; cin >> value2;
        cout << " The result for the Entered values is equal to: "; cout << (value1 + value2);
        break;

        case '-':
        cout << " Enter your first Number: "; cin >> value1; cout << " Enter your second number: "; cin >> value2;
        cout << " The result for the Entered values is equal to: "; cout << (value1 - value2);
        break;

        case '*':
        cout << " Enter your first Number: "; cin >> value1; cout << " Enter your second number: "; cin >> value2;
        cout << " The result for the Entered values is equal to: "; cout << (value1 * value2);
        break;

        case '/':
            if(!(value2))
                cout << "INFINITY" << '\n';
            else
        cout << " Enter your first Number: "; cin >> value1;
        cout << " Enter your second number: "; cin >> value2;
        cout << " The result for the Entered values is equal to: " << (value1 / value2) << '\n';
        break;

       default:
        cout << " Unidentified or Wrong Input / maybe not allowed! Try again." << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: `value2` is not initialized when you get to the `if(!(value2))` line - therefore your code invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: The `else` branch is just `cout << " Enter your first Number: ";`. Read about blocks and curly braces in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: you can read about division by 0 in c++ here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745311/c-division-by-0

Comment: @UnholySheep by doing if(value2) it return the same behavior.

Comment: The point is you checked the value of `value2` before you asked the user to enter it. You need to put your if after you input the value not before

Comment: @molbdnilo I have finished it thus I have written my own code which I think is Valid but I don't know why it's not valid.

Comment: Your code is absolutely not valid. This is undefined behavior to use value2 when it has not been initilaized.

Comment: It not valid because you check the value **before** then user enters it, You should do it **afterwards**. There are other problems as well.

Comment: @drescherjm How?

Comment: Read about Undefined Behavior

Comment: read about the use of uninitialized variables: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/uninitialized-variables-and-undefined-behavior/

Comment: @john You mean to reverse the statement?

Comment: @Tahir Move the if statement so that is is **after** the `cin >> ` statement. You cannot check the value of a variable **before** that variable has a value.

Comment: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) your case is Uninitialized scalar

Comment: @Tahir Yes, reverse the order. Get the value first, check the value second.

Comment: @Tahir You haven't "finished" the book if you haven't learned the most fundamental things from it.

Comment: @john Ok, I get to the point )

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes I will repeat it one more time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're checking if value2 is equal to 0 before receiving the user's input, when it is uninitialized.

Do this:

```
case '/':
        cout << " Enter your first Number: "; cin >> value1;
        cout << " Enter your second number: "; cin >> value2;
        if(value2)
            cout << " The result for the Entered values is equal to: " << (value1 / value2) << '\n';
        else
            cout << "INFINITY" << '\n';
        break;
```

Answer (score 1):

that's normal, because you're using value2 here without initialisation and this a runtime failure :

```
case '/':
        if (!(value2))
            std::cout << "INFINITY" << '\n';
```

try this instead:

```
case '/':
        std::cout << " Enter your first Number: "; std::cin >> value1;
        std::cout << " Enter your second number: "; std::cin >> value2;
        if (!(value2))
            std::cout << "INFINITY" << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << " The result for the Entered values is equal to: " << (value1 / value2) << '\n';
        break;
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge )