# Why it throws "Floating Point Exception" if I divide a floating number by zero?

Tags: linux

As titled.

As I know about the floating-point number, if we try to divide a floating-point number by zero, the result could actually be a "∞", namely infinity. And it also could be represented in floating-point number format as I showed below. So, why does the Linux system need to raise an exception rather than just doing what I expected? (the exception is raised by the underlying system)

[image]

Comment: It depends on the language you are using, on the specific compiler, if it is compiled. For example in C++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745311/c-division-by-0/4745343

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividing by 0 does not necessarily result in infinity. There's a good [numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRRolKTlF6Q) video that goes into this.

More importantly here, the IEEE 754 floating point standard (which is what most languages/cpus use) dictates that dividing by 0 should result in NaN, and many programming languages just turn this into an error.

This is not linux specific. I don't even think Linux itself can raise something called an exception, so this must be a higher-level language thing.

Comment: It seems for IEEE floats, division of a finite nonzero float by 0 is well-defined and results in +infinity (if the value was >zero) or -infinity (if the value was less than zero). The result of 0.0/0.0 is NaN.