# 0 divided by 0 results in 1 in g++ 10.2

Tags: c++, g++

The following code prints `gcc says: 0 / 0 equals 1` when compiled with `g++` 10.2:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int a = 0;
  std::cout << "gcc says: 0 / 0 equals " << (a / a) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

[Run it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bs6W7h)

- Is this supposed to be this way? (Compiling with `clang` and executing it returns 136 - Erroneous Arithmetic Operation).
- Is this the result of some kind of code optimization?
- Is there a way to make this an error?

Edit: Compiling with `-fsanitize=undefined` makes `g++` to produce a runtime error. Thanks to @chris.

Comment: Moral of the story: undefined behavior really is undefined behavior. *Integer* division by zero is not defined in C++, so the compiler is well within its right to assume that `a / a` is always `1`. The case where `a` is 0 is not simply not possible in its eyes.

Comment: Replace `(a / a)` with `(a ? std::to_string(a / a) : "oopsies")` or whatever you want the fail situation to be.

Comment: I imagine `-fsanitize=undefined` goes some way to more reliable error detection here. In addition, I noticed the godbolt link has no warning options and those are typically good at preventing some classes of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ division by 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745311/c-division-by-0)

Comment: @chris, thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Division by zero is undefined behavior. The compiler will proceed to do whatever makes the code run fastest. And it won't even be consistent about it.

There is no way to make this result in a compiler error, because the compiler won't always know if the denominator is 0 at compile time.  You have to do the checks yourself.